# Как заменить часть строки в поле MySQL

Tags: mysql

Доброго всем дня! В общем такой вопрос, как в MySQL заменить часть строкового поля, зная индекс символа и длинну для замены? Что-то вроде REPLACE, но по индексу  в общем

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Что есть "индекс символа"? Судя по тексту - это явно не позиция... иначе неясно, чем не устраивает INSERT().

Comment: Это позиция символа в строке. Insert, насколько знаю, умеет вставлять целиком строку в таблицу, а не изменять часть ячейки в строке

Comment: @Александр, другой insert: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_insert

Comment: Пожалуй, то что надо, спасибо